# If I show that an iterated integral is less than $\infty$, does it necessarily mean that the integral is finite?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am currently trying to show that an function has a finite integral. I am trying to find the iterated integral of:

$$
\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}
$$

over $-\infty < \alpha, \beta <\infty$.

I am able to see that $\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}} < e^{|\alpha + 0.3\beta|}$, and that $\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}} < e^{|\alpha + 0.05\beta|}$.

Hence, I have that:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}} d\alpha d\beta
$$

$$
< \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{|\alpha + 0.3\beta|} e^{|\alpha + 0.05\beta|}d\alpha d\beta = \infty
$$

How I got the $\infty$ was by looking at the four cases, when $|\alpha + 0.3\beta|$ is greater than or less than 0, and when $|\alpha + 0.05\beta|$ is greater than or less than 0. However, if I look at alpha, it will either be $e^{-\alpha}e^{\alpha} = 1$, $e^{\alpha}e^{\alpha} = e^{2\alpha}$, or $e^{-\alpha}e^{-\alpha} = e^{-2\alpha}$. In any of these cases, the integral with $d\alpha$ will be infinity. Would this suffice to conclude that:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}} d\alpha d\beta < \infty
$$
?

Thanks!

Comment: Without $g$ being integrable, from the pointwise $|f| < g$, you will only have $\int|f| \le \int g$, not the strict inequality. For example $\int_{\mathbf R} x^2 \dx = \infty$, but $x^2 =: f(x) < g(x) := x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot conclude this. For you to prove something is non-infinite, you need to find an upper bound $M$ (and also a lower bound $-M$) such that $-M \leq \int f(x) dx \leq M$. Where $M$ is some constant.

A counter example to what you have said:

$$\infty = \int_{0}^\infty x dx < \int_{0}^\infty 2x dx = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, rather than answer you question, my advice: linearly change the variables to $x = \alpha + 0.05\beta$ and y = $\alpha + 0.3\beta$. This is a linear transform and changes the result of the integral by only a constant factor. The integral then becomes much more tractable after separating variables, and possibly some further changes of variables.